# dd or equivalent everything on a disk without dding the entire disk

Tags: partitioning, dd

I have a very specific kernel structure on an sd card I'd like to copy and send to a friend.

I know I can simply dd the entire SD card, but the kernel is ~2GB, which wastes the other 14GB of the disk.

Is there a way to dd just the important parts?

I know I can also dd the individual partitions, but this requires setting up an equivalent partition table on the other side, so I'd prefer to do this in a way that requires only a single dd to the child disk, regardless of the complexity of creating the parent.

Comment: `dd` copies *blocks* of amorphous data. It looks as if you wanted to copy *files*.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware DD doesn't look at the data, I was wondering if there was some trick with getting the size from the devices and using that as an argument to dd

Comment: To repeat, `dd` copies **blocks** of data. It has no idea of a filesystem. What makes you think that the files you want to copy are contiguous and placed at a well-known place on the disk?

Comment: Ah good point, I forgot that journaling systems put the files everywhere. I guess my question then is would rsync or even just tar/send over the net be adapted (with other applications as well) to work across partitions?

Comment: I don't know, never tried. Why don't you send *the recipe* for making that kernel structure? Presumably your kernel structure is made by running a script or set of commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Clonezilla,

http://clonezilla.org

- Download a Clonezilla iso file, make a CD boot disk or USB boot drive and boot from it.
- Create a compressed image of the whole drive (a Clonezilla image is a directory with a number of files, where the big files are compressed). Clonezilla is smart enough to only clone the used blocks (and skip blocks, that are not used).
- Test that it works to restore from the image, and when you know that it works, you can send the image to your friend.